# JavaScript: using Flattr API. how to wait until API is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the [Flattr JavaScript API](https://flattr.com/support/integrate/js). I included the loading code as described.

But `FlattrLoader.setup()` does not work. I am getting the exception `ReferenceError: FlattrLoader is not defined`.

I tried both

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FlattrLoader.setup();
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload = function(){ FlattrLoader.setup(); }
</script>
```

That is strange because in the `load.js` from the API, I see `var FlattrLoader = { ... }`.

I use Chrome. From its Developer Tools, it seems that the `load.js` gets loaded (at least it lists it there).

Maybe I must do some extra handling that it waits with the execution until the `load.js` is really loaded? The only explanation why it fails is that the site-loading itself is finished
before `load.js` can be loaded. How would such extra handling look like?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

```
function loadFlattr() {
    if(typeof(FlattrLoader) == "undefined")
        setTimeout(loadFlattr, 100);
    else
        FlattrLoader.setup(); 
}
loadFlattr();
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

since this is an old thread, I don't know if you've fixed this, but you should check out the current version of the documentation. The code is a lot easier and also async now

https://flattr.com/support/integrate/js